# Removing a new line from the very last line of a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
tocheck = 'abc:def:ghi'

with open("file1.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    with open("file1.txt", "w") as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(lines):
            a,b,c = line.split(':')
            if f'{a}:{b}' == tocheck:
                print('found it')
                with open("file2.txt", 'a') as ban:
                    ban.write(f'\n{tocheck} was found')
            else:
                if i == len(lines)-1:
                    f.writelines(line.rstrip("\n"))
                else:
                    f.writelines(line)
```

hey, so i have 2 text files, `file1` and `file2`
My idea is to check `file1` looking for a specific line and, if it is found, it will be written on `file2` and removed from `file1`

until here, everything works, my problem is that the very last line of `file1` can't end up having a new line at the end of it, but it still does and I have no idea on how to remove that `\n` from the **last line only**

Comment: `f.write` may be better than `f.writelines`; the latter is for a list of lines, not for a single line.

Comment: This is not a [mre] so we will have a hard time helping unless you explain better how it doesn't work

Comment: Your code will work fine, as long as the last line of file1 does not match `tocheck`. If that last line does match `tocheck`, the penultimate line will become the last line in your new file1, but the `i == len(lines)-1` will fail, and thus the newline will not be stripped.